# restoring view's counter

Tags: facebook, view

I have an additional page called "precious feet" and when I first set it up I could view the amount of visits it got, however now it won't show this information, it also gives me the option to "like" which it never did before and I assume that is because it is my page and of course I will like it. Can anybody help me restore the functions. I have tried logging out and back in again but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't the page admin anymore or you have a group not a page. Try clicking on the down arrow on the top right and under "Use Facebook as:" select your page. If it isn't there then it's likely you are no longer a page admin.